# Selectable procedure extremely slow with timestamp

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT
    "TRIP"."ID" as "ID",
    "TRIP"."KEY" as "TRIP_KEY",
    "ROUTE"."KEY" as "ROUTE_KEY",
    "ROUTE"."AGENCY_ID" as "AGENCY_ID",
    "TRIP"."BLOCK" as "BLOCK",
    "TRIP"."DIRECTION" as "DIRECTION",
    "CALENDAR"."MASK" as "MASK",
    "CALENDAR"."START_DATE",
    "CALENDAR"."END_DATE",
    "TRIP"."CALENDAR_ID" as "CALENDAR_ID"
    FROM "STOP_TIME" 
    JOIN "FEED" ON("STOP_TIME"."FEED_ID"="FEED"."ID") 
    JOIN "TRIP" ON ("STOP_TIME"."TRIP_ID"="TRIP"."ID") 
    JOIN "CALENDAR" ON("TRIP"."CALENDAR_ID"="CALENDAR"."ID") 
    JOIN "ROUTE" ON("TRIP"."ROUTE_ID"="ROUTE"."ID")
WHERE 
    "FEED"."REALTIME_FEED"='TrainFeed' AND 
    "FEED"."ACTIVE" = true AND 
    "CALENDAR"."START_DATE" <= '15.03.2019 11:00' AND 
    "CALENDAR"."END_DATE" >= '10.03.2019 11:00' AND
    "STOP_TIME"."DEPARTURE_TIME" >= 0 AND 
    "STOP_TIME"."DEPARTURE_TIME" < 39600000
```

Which gives me the following runtime behaviour (output from FlameRobin):

> Executing statement...
>   Statement executed (elapsed time: 0.000s).
>   4287 fetches, 0 marks, 1847 reads, 0 writes.
>   0 inserts, 0 updates, 0 deletes, 722 index, 3 seq.
>   Delta memory: 1415008 bytes.
>   **Total execution time: 0.322s**
>   Script execution finished.

However, if I put this query in a selectable procedure:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_TIMETABLE (
    FEEDNAME varchar(100),
    CALENDAR_TIME timestamp,
    TIME_FROM integer,
    TIME_TO integer)
RETURNS (
    ID bigint,
    TRIP_KEY varchar(100),
    ROUTE_KEY varchar(100),
    AGENCY_ID bigint,
    "BLOCK" varchar(100),
    DIRECTION smallint,
    MASK smallint,
    CALENDAR_ID bigint)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE valid_trip BOOLEAN;
BEGIN 
    FOR SELECT
        "TRIP"."ID" as "ID",
        "TRIP"."KEY" as "TRIP_KEY",
        "ROUTE"."KEY" as "ROUTE_KEY",
        "ROUTE"."AGENCY_ID" as "AGENCY_ID",
        "TRIP"."BLOCK" as "BLOCK",
        "TRIP"."DIRECTION" as "DIRECTION",
        "CALENDAR"."MASK" as "MASK",
        "TRIP"."CALENDAR_ID" as "CALENDAR_ID"
    FROM "STOP_TIME" 
        JOIN "FEED" ON("STOP_TIME"."FEED_ID"="FEED"."ID") 
        JOIN "TRIP" ON ("STOP_TIME"."TRIP_ID"="TRIP"."ID") 
        JOIN "CALENDAR" ON("TRIP"."CALENDAR_ID"="CALENDAR"."ID") 
        JOIN "ROUTE" ON("TRIP"."ROUTE_ID"="ROUTE"."ID")
    WHERE 
        "FEED"."REALTIME_FEED"=:feedName AND 
        "FEED"."ACTIVE" = true AND 
        "CALENDAR"."START_DATE" <= :calendar_time AND 
        "CALENDAR"."END_DATE" >= :calendar_time AND 
        "STOP_TIME"."DEPARTURE_TIME" >= :time_from AND 
        "STOP_TIME"."DEPARTURE_TIME" < :time_to
    INTO :id, :trip_key, :route_key, :agency_id, :block, :direction, :mask, :calendar_id DO 
    BEGIN
        SUSPEND;
    END
END^
SET TERM ;
```

and call it with the same parameters:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID, p.TRIP_KEY, 
    p.ROUTE_KEY, 
    p.AGENCY_ID, 
    p."BLOCK", 
    p.DIRECTION,
    p.MASK, p.CALENDAR_ID
FROM SELECT_TIMETABLE (
    'TrainFeed', 
    '15.03.2019 11:00', 
    0, 
    39600000) p;
```

I get a much worse runtime behaviour:

> Executing statement...
>  
>   Statement executed (elapsed time: 0.000s).
>   3248968 fetches, 0 marks, 52540 reads, 0 writes.
>   0 inserts, 0 updates, 0 deletes, 1338852 index, 42 seq.
>   Delta memory: 784 bytes. 
>   **Total execution time: 3.477s**
>   Script execution finished.

I have narrowed it down to the filtering of the START_DATE and END_DATE of the CALENDAR table. If I omit the filter, the execution time goes down to half a second. In addition to that, the selectable procedure above also doesn't give any results (with the START_DATE/END_DATE filtering) where as the query does.

So there seems to be something wrong with my selectable procedure. But I can't see the issue.

Firebird Version is 3.0.4.33054 (x64) on Windows. I'm using Firebird currently as embedded server.

Comment: What is the type of `"CALENDAR"."START_DATE"` and `"CALENDAR"."END_DATE"`? What happens if - in the original query - you replace `"CALENDAR"."START_DATE" <= '15.03.2019 11:00'` with `"CALENDAR"."START_DATE" <= timestamp'15.03.2019 11:00'` (and the same for the comparison with `END_DATE`)?

Comment: `"CALENDAR"."START_DATE"` and `"CALENDAR"."END_DATE"` are both of the type `TIMESTAMP`. Changing the query as you described has no positive or negative effect, (Total execution time: 0.393s)

Comment: I've recreated the procedure now multiple times and (for whatever reason) the selectable procedure works now as expected. I stil can't understand what the problem was in first place. Maybe a corrupted database? I also should mention that I've added the selectable procedure not during the creation of the database. I did have the db in use for some time at that point. I don't know if that plays a role...

Comment: It may play a role. Because when you have real data in tables you have somewhat real statistics for indexes and that affects what `plan` the optimizer builds for the query. As far as i understand, for explicit queries plan is built during preparatino of the query, but with SP it owld be built once and for all when creating the procedure. Thus if you create SP before filling in data the plan may be suboptimal. But maybe i am plain wrong on it.

Comment: but yeah, it would be more correct comparison, if you start with using explicit query with parameters too, to be just like the SP query, rather than using literals in the query but params in SP. Also i'd try `.... :calendar_time BETWEEN  "CALENDAR"."START_DATE" AND  "CALENDAR"."END_DATE" ...` condition instead. And i'd put all the conditions between ANDs and ORs into explicit parenthesis, just to be on a safe side. P.S. `"FEED"."ACTIVE" = true` - why redundancy? `if true=true=true=true=true=t`... Buffallo buffalo buffalo...

Comment: Index statistics don't automatically update, so repeatedly recreating a procedure by itself would not be enough to get a different plan, although it does sound like a new plan was selected.